# Positive way of saying emotional appeal?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a positive way of saying argumentum ad passiones?

Comment: Iffy, but: *You tug at my heartstrings* http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tug+at+the+heartstrings

Comment: This site is not a translation service. And you haven't explained what's wrong with the conventional translation "appeal to emotion". And you haven't explained what you mean by "positive".

Comment: Appeal to emotion implies logical fallacy.

Comment: An *impassioned plea*.

Comment: Don't you think _any_ alternative is going to be negative (because it will be a fallacy)? Or do you really want a positive version of fallacy or bias?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make it any truer--it is a logical fallacy after all--but if it makes you feel better, try ***ardent assertion:***

*[ardent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ardent)*

> adjective
>
> 1 Very enthusiastic or passionate:
>
> *ODO*

*[assertion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/assertion)*

> noun
>
> 1 A confident and forceful statement of fact or belief:
>
> *ODO*

An *impassioned appeal* is not necessarily false, but it is not necessarily as true as it feels.